# Destructor patterns in software architechture

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, software-design

Just as **Factory Pattern**, **Builder Pattern**, etc are **Creational Patterns**.

Does any **Destructor pattern** exist?

If any... name some.

Answer (score 2):

In languages with manual memory management like C++, the destructor exists to cleanup resources like allocated objects, opened file handles etc.

If an object **A** has reference to object **B** and **A** is resposible for the life-cycle of **B** then in it's destructor **A** *must* call *delete* **B**, so that it's destructor is called an so on. This ensures that all objects allocated as part of **A** are deleted and the memory is returned to the system otherwise you get memory leaks.

In languages with automatic memory management (garbage collection) there is no need for an object to *delete* other objects contained by it because the system will remove all unused objects.

In those languages, objects still can allocate resources like files, acquire locks, start timers etc, so that an action is required when they are no longer needed to release these resources.

In these languages [The Dispose pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispose_pattern) is used.

In the general case this pattern consists of a method (Close, Destroy, Release etc.) that releases these resouces and must be called. Usually it's used in a finnaly {} block of a try {} catch{} finnaly {} construct.

C# has the **IDisposable** interface that can use used with the *using* declaration, so it has a build in support for it.

I don't have much experience with Java so as far as I know Java 7 introduced [AutoClosable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html), but it's used with try { } finally { }

In C# you can also add a finalizer than is called when an object is garbage collected. You can use this finalizer to release resources or add assertions that an object was properly disposed before GC to catch bugs. I've used it to catch bugs for objects that allocate important resources and it's hard to find out where the bugs come from.